# pfquerytableview only getting partial data from pointer

Tags: swift, pointers

I have the following query for table.

```
override func queryForTable() -> PFQuery {

    var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    var user = PFUser.currentUser()!
    query.whereKey("createdByUser", equalTo: user)
    return query
}
```

On the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, I managed to get the object that is stored within pointer at the column `bellongsToStyle`

```
    if let object  = object?["bellongsToStyle"] as? PFObject {

        styleObject = object

        println("BELLONGS TO STYLE- \(styleObject)")
    }
```

My output for the print above comes like that and so far I get the object...

> BELLONGS TO STYLE -  Styles: 0x7fdcd3c04d20, objectId: G29f9Wfqj5,
>   localId: (null)

But, there is another column within the object Styles and this column is called `description`. Unfortunately I haven't been able to get the data inside `description`. WHile I can get the objectId, createAt, etc...

If I try something like this to retrieve the `description` within the object I get nothing.

```
if let object  = object?["bellongsToStyle"] as? PFObject {

    styleObject = object

    styleString = styleObject.objectForKey("description") as! String

}
```

I assume when you retrieve an object with a pointer, all the data within the pointer comes with it, doesn't it? Why in my case I am just getting parts of this object?

I could send another query just to get the whole pointer object as a last resource but don't think that is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, queries on objects will not retrieve any further than the first layer of data. You do however, get the basic properties - objectId, createdAt - of pointers. This is documented behaviour.

If you want your query to also return the full details of that pointer object, you need to use the `includeKey:` method of `PFQuery`, which will extend your query to grab the defined object.

```
var query = PFQuery(className: "Posts")
query.includeKey("belongToStyle") //will fetch style object
```

Now, you'll have access to the Posts object, and the Style object.